# How to get this javascript code working on Mac

Tags: javascript, ios, macos

How can i get this code working on Safari (Mac OS)

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById("name").src = "../index.html";
document.getElementById("name").herf = "http://google.com/index.html";
```

**html**

```
<iframe id="name" src="../imghp" width="30%" height="103" name="iamiframe">
            <p>Your Brower doesn't support iframe so: <a href="http://google.com/imghp">click</a></p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to exactly ?

Because, if you want to embed the google page in your iframe , and expect this this error link if the iframe is not supported

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="name" src="" width="30%" height="103" name="iamiframe">
    <p>Your Brower doesn't support iframe so: <a href="http://google.com/imghp">click</a></p>
</iframe>


<script>
    // or you can directly put in on the src iframe attribute
    document.getElementById("name").src = 'http://www.test.com';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code seems to be working, and for you ?

PS : if you want to iframe directly google.com , you we'll handle this error : Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JaOAVIe9GefE8genlYCoAQ&gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Hope this help,

C